# How to sent a email outside Wordpress?

Tags: php

I am setting up a paid membership page on WordPress. It uses a form to get credit card information and an email address, then runs the card and on success sets up a new user. I can run the card, and creates a new user, but it doesn't send them a Welcome email so they can establish their own password.

I have tried to find the right combination of include files for this PHP page (using echo statements to see where the code breaks) and have addressed a lot of the missing functions by including them at the top of the page, but I still get "Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /[...]/wp-includes/cache.php on line 113". Here is the code I have created to try to send a notification email:

```
require_once('../wp-includes/capabilities.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/cache.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/option.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/plugin.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/formatting.php');
function setWP($username){
    global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;
    echo("Globals<br />");

    $user_login=$username;
    echo($user_login."<br />");

    if(empty($user_login)){
        return false;
    }else if(strpos($user_login, '@')){
        $user_data=get_user_by('email', trim($user_login));
        if(empty($user_data))
            return false;
    }else{
        $login=trim($user_login);
        $user_data=get_user_by('login', $login);
    }
    echo("user_login<br />");

    do_action('lostpassword_post');


    if(!$user_data) return false;

    // redefining user_login ensures we return the right case in the email
    $user_login=$user_data->user_login;
    $user_email=$user_data->user_email;

    do_action('retreive_password', $user_login);  // Misspelled and deprecated
    do_action('retrieve_password', $user_login);
    echo("retrieve_password<br />");

    $allow=apply_filters('allow_password_reset', true, $user_data->ID);

    if(!$allow)
        return false;
    else if(is_wp_error($allow))
        return false;
    echo("allow<br />");

    $key=wp_generate_password(20, false);
    do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);

    if(empty($wp_hasher)){
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';
        $wp_hasher=new PasswordHash(8, true);
    }
    $hashed=$wp_hasher->HashPassword($key);
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $hashed), array('user_login' => $user_login));
    echo("hashed<br />");

    $message=__('Welcome!') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('If you did not request a training series, send an email to info@url.com.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('As a new student, you will need to set a password. Visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";

    if(is_multisite())
        $blogname=$GLOBALS['current_site']->site_name;
    else
        $blogname=wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
    echo("is_multisite<br />");

    $title=sprintf(__('[%s] Password Reset'), $blogname);

    $title=apply_filters('retrieve_password_title', $title);
    $message=apply_filters('retrieve_password_message', $message, $key);
    echo("Prep to send<br />");

    if($message && !wp_mail($user_email, $title, $message))
        echo('The e-mail could not be sent.');
    else
        echo("Message sent.");

}
```

Is there a way to send a Welcome email to the user outside of the WordPress framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are outside Wordpress and want to load Wordpess, you only need:

```
require ('/path/to/wp-load.php');
```

In some situations you may want to load only some Wordpress functions, for example:

```
define('SHORTINIT', true);
require ('/path/to/wp-load.php');
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );
//Load more files if you need
```

Anyway, I think this is the wrong way. You say that you are in a Wordpress page, so why do you get outsite Wordpress? Are you making an Ajax request? If so you should use the Ajax API. See:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29
- http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Yes, I am making an AJAX request. I'll scour the API reference. Thanks